Must there exist, somewhere in the sequence an odd number immediately followed by an even number?
A given sequence contains every positive integer exactly once, and no other terms.
Must there exist, somewhere in the sequence an odd number immediately followed by an even number?
Bonus question:  Must there exist, somewhere in the sequence a multiple of two immediately followed by a multiple of three?

Attribution:  http://puzzlecritic.wordpress.com/

Main question:

Assume per absurdo that no even number in the sequence follows an odd number.

That is equivalent to saying that every even number in the sequence is either the first number or follows an even number.


Then, by induction, the sequence must contain all and only the even numbers.

But that is impossible, as there is every odd number in the sequence, by surjectivity.

Bonus question:

Since there are infinitely many numbers in the sequence that are neither multiples of 2 nor of 3, it is easy to construct a counter-example.


Just take the sequence of positive integers in their natural order, but for every successive numbers that are multiples of 2 and 3 resp., place in between the first unused power of 5 (and skip it when you later reach it in the natural order).  There is always one such number that we can pick.

Namely, that is the sequence:
1 2 5 3 4 5^2 6 7 8 5^3 9 10 11 12 13 14 5^4 15 16 17 18 19 20 5^5 21 22 23 24 26...


Your main answer appears to assume that it can contain only even numbers, but nothing prior to that suggests that leap is valid. Additionally, there are different levels of infinity - while there are an infinite number of powers of 5, there are more gaps that need to be filled in a sample size than powers of 5 and thus the process is not sustainable.

A +1 immediately followed by a -1... :)  Some people are thinking "n-infinite" sequences, but those aren't sequences: plus, by that token, both questions become easily answerable, since an "n-infinite" sequence can be used to partition the positive integers in n disjoint classes, i.e. as many disjoint classes as one likes.

@TakingNotes  A sequence is a sequence: see my previous comment.  Also I don't know what you mean by your first objection, I am making no such assumption.

1 3 2 4 5 6 7 9 8 10 11 12 13 15 14 16 17 18 19 21 20 . . .

@DanielMathias : you just swap when needed , right?

How can an 'n-infinite' sequence not be a sequence when it is quite literally in the name? To clarify my first objection, nothing in the statement rot13("rirel rira ahzore va gur frdhrapr vf rvgure gur svefg ahzore be sbyybjf na rira ahzore") dictates that rot13(gur frdhrapr pbagnvaf bayl rira ahzoref, bayl gung vg zhfg ortva jvgu rirel rira ahzore)

@FirstNameLastName That's right. You could also have 2 1 3 4 5 6 8 7 9 10 11 12 14 13 15 17 18 20 19 21 . . .

@TakingNotes: A "sequence" in mathematics is, by definition, a mapping from the natural numbers to something. So for anything that's present in the sequence, you can always give a natural number (or numbers) which will tell you what position(s) that thing can be found at. If you have a sequence where "all even numbers come before any odd numbers", what position does number 1 come at?

You are correct that some infinities are bigger than others. You are wrong that it is relevant here, there are as many unique powers of five as there are numbers in the sequence, so there are more than enough available for filling a subsequence of gaps. @TakingNotes

Main question:

 No, it is not required that there will be an odd number immediately followed by an even number. This is because we can imagine a sequence which contains every single even number, then every single odd number. 
 i.e. 2, 4, 6, 8... 1, 3, 5, 7...

Bonus question:

 No, it is not required that there will be a multiple of 2 followed by a multiple of 3. This is because we can imagine a sequence which contains every single odd multiple of 3, then intercutting between odd non-multiples of 3, and even multiples of 3, then finishing with the even non-multiples of 3. 
 i.e. 3, 9, 15, 21... 1, 6, 5, 12, 7, 18, 11, 24... 2, 4, 8, 10... 
 For this to work, we need to prove that there will be more odd non-multiples of 3 than even multiples of 3 (aka even multiples of 6). This can be done by considering the six consecutive numbers that begin with a multiple of 6, as follows: 
6n, 6n+1, 6n+2, 6n+3, 6n+4, 6n+5
 Of this set, 6n+1 and 6n+5 will be odd non-multiples of 3, and 6n will be the only multiple of 6. This shows that for every multiple of 6, there will be 2 odd non-multiples of 3, and thus we will never run out of numbers when on an infinite scale.


Posted an answer, but it was basically the same so deleted it.

But rot13(n frdhrapr juvpu pbagnvaf rirel fvatyr rira ahzore, gura rirel fvatyr bqq ahzore) is not a sequence...

You yourself just described it as a sequence, no? Plus, it can be pretty easily described using parametrics.

@TakingNotes : all right!  So what is first element of your counter example sequence? I guess: any even number? What do you refer to with parametrics ? I am willing to learn !

It is not formally a sequence. The domain of a sequence is the natural numbers. You do not assign "1" to any natural number index. You could conceptualize your sequence-like object as having as its domain the ordinal number ω·2 in which case the index of "1" is ω -- but that would not usually be understood to be a sequence.

@tehtmi Just had to upvote this, as this is puzzling.SE, not mathematics.SE and the (in)ability of current mathematics to define "the sequence of all even numbers followed by all odd numbers" should have no relation with the ability of an English language puzzle to define such a sequence.

And btw, just to be clear, I downvoted the question primarily because a question that can be answered using basic english plus very basic mathematics, but whose meaning changes with a more in depth understanding of maths is frankly just a bad question. I just took issue with those who acted like a specific more restrictive definition of sequence is categorically "the correct one".

what is the position of the first odd number in your imaginary sequence (main question)?

As a mathematician (logician), I think most mathematicians would happily call this a sequence — specifically, an ω·2-indexed sequence, as @tehtmi points out — but, at the same time, the default meaning of “sequence” is as an ℕ-indexed sequence, and it’s clear in the question that that’s what was meant here.  This is a fun outside-the-box answer, but also reasonably clearly not within the question’s intent.

@DavidMulder: 1) There is a math tag, present here. 2) Mathematics can indeed define and understand this thing, as I mentioned. That is not at issue. 3) If this was a chess puzzle that hinged on a chess rule that not everyone knows, I don't think there would be so much fuss about pointing out a mistaken understanding of that rule, even if a layperson could easily make that mistake and notwithstanding our ability to play chess with alternate rules if we wanted to. Maybe understanding that rule is the whole point. 4) Subjectivity, obviously (except maybe the math).

For those who don't like the accumulation point before the odd numbers, you can also reverse all the even numbers to get a two-way-infinite (Z-indexed) sequence.

It is called a bi-infinite sequence.

A comment said

It is not formally a sequence. The domain of a sequence is the natural numbers. You do not assign "1" to any natural number index. You could conceptualize your sequence-like object as having as its domain the ordinal number ω·2 in which case the index of "1" is ω -- but that would not usually be understood to be a sequence.

Here is an answer similar to the one of TakingNotes but that uses (non-standard) natural numbers (not infinite ordinals) as indices. The sequence contains all non-nonzero natural numbers, including non-standard natural numbers.

 You can skip this secton.
 Assume ZFC axioms. These axioms prove Peano arithmetic is consistent.
 Consider Peano arithmetic with a constant k and the following axioms added:
 k>0, k>s(0), k>s(s(0)), k>s(s(s(0))), ...
 Here s represents successor (so s(0)=1, s(1)=2, ...)
 Any finite subset is consistent so by the compactness theorem (as all the axioms are first-order) the whole thing is consistent. By the completeness theorem, this theory has a model, which is obviously infinite.
 By the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, this theory has countably infinite models because it has a countable set of axioms and is first-order and it has infinite models. (One might consider instead a non-standard model of Presburger arithmetic, which has only $+$ but no $\times$ so it can still define even and odd.)


 Let $(N, +, \times, s, 0, k)$ denote a countably infinite non-standard model of Peano arithmetic. Let $E$ denote the set $\{x\in N\mid\exists y\in N(y+y=x)\land x\neq0\}$. Let $O$ denote $\{x\in N\mid x\notin E\land x\neq0\}$. Let $A$ denote $\{0,s(0),s(s(0)),s(s(s(0))),\dots\}$ (the standard natural numbers and $B$ denote $\{x\in N\mid x\notin A\}$. The model is non-standard so $A\neq N$. So $A$, $B$, $E$, $O$, $N$ are all countably infinite.


 Let $f$ denote a bijection from $A$ to $E$ and $g$ denote a bijection from $B$ to $O$. Let $h$ represent the combined bijection (from $N$ to $N-\{0\}$). Every even number is immediately followed by an even number and every odd number is immediately followed by an odd number. So no odd number is immediately followed by an even number.


 The sequence $h$ contains all natural numbers in $N$ apart from $0$. One can modify $E$ and $O$ to contain only standard natural numbers. ($E$ and $O$ are still countably infinite so bijections still exist) This $h$ is a sequence where indices are natural numbers (including non-standard natural numbers) but the values are all standard.


Well, formally, "non-standard" and "infinite" are the same.  Besides, your "sequence contains all non-nonzero natural numbers, including non-standard natural numbers" and then it is not a sequence as per the question, which "contains every positive integer exactly once, and no other terms."  No?

Main Question

 Nope, simply enumerate all the even numbers first, and then the odd numbers. That way all the even numbers will be before all the odd numbers so an even number cannot possibly be after an odd number.

Bonus Question

 Nope as well, start with all the odd multiples of 3, after that alternate between the multiples of 2 and the numbers that are neither multiples of 2 or multiples of 3. That way there will never be a multiple of 2 followed by a multiple of 3.


Why -1? explain?

Not from me, but your main idea has already been given, e.g. in the answer of TakingNotes where, as discussed in the comments, myself and others have noted that it is not really allowed if we take a normal mathematical interpretation of the question.

Ok,the sequence is infinitely long because it contains all of the positive numbers.  If you define the sequence such that all of the even numbers are listed before any of the odd numbers, then no. Simple as that.
Now you can't enumerate this sequence.  If you try you will note that you never run out of even numbers, but that is the absurdity of infinity.  The reducto ad absurdium doesn't work because infinity has absurdity.
In my grade school, 65 years ago, I was taught that the size of the set of all the even counting numbers was the same as the size of the set of all counting numbers.  More lately I would believe that the infinities are different sized, because you can show that there is a correspondence mismatch.  I believe both of those contradicting statements to be true, it just depends on how you look at the absurdity of infinity.
As to the multiple of two followed by the multiple of 3, consider first that we have put the even numbers first. Some of those even numbers will be multiples of three.  There will be more than one multiple of two that is also a multiple of three, so no matter how you arrange the sequence there will be a multiple of three that follows an even number.
While we might be able to construct a sequence where every multiple of three is not preceeded by an even number, that would force you to mix the odd and even numbers, so that would not be the first sequence.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

"the size of the set of all the even counting numbers was the same as the size of the set of all counting numbers. More lately I would believe that the infinities are different sized..." and your belief would be incorrect. Every non-negative even number is twice a natural number, so they are in 1:1 correspondence and there are the same amount of both NN evens and naturals. You may think it's absurd, but this is just your intuition not being developed for infinities.
